# Calculate the summary statistics of an image in R

Tags: r, image, image-processing, statistics

I'm interested to calculate the summary statistics of an image including mean, median, standard deviation, skewness and kurtosis. It's for detecting what kind of pixel distribution of an image is. In particular, I want to do it in R/RStudio, not Python.

I start with an example of a cat image below:

[Cat picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAlZu.jpg)

and the code:

```
library(imager)
cat <- load.image(file = "~/Desktop/img.jpg")
plot(cat)
c(mean(cat), median(cat), sd(cat))
## [1] 0.4006788 0.3137255 0.2872094

library(moments)
c(skewness(cat), kurtosis(cat))
## [1] 0.3670244 1.5719933
```

1. Is this a correct way of calculating the summary statistics of an image?
2. Also, as the cat image is coloured, how to do this channel-wise (RGB) for each summary statistic?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found solutions to my questions. For the first question, it is correct and alternatively, it can be written as a function:

```
library(OpenImageR)
calculate_image_stats <- function(image_path) {
  library(moments)
  image <- readImage(image_path)  # read the image into a matrix
  stats <- list()
  stats$mean <- mean(image)
  stats$median <- median(image)
  stats$sd <- sd(image)
  stats$skewness <- skewness(image)
  stats$kurtosis <- kurtosis(image)
  return(stats)
}
```

For the second question, I have three matrices from readImage, which each corresponds to a colour channel. So, I can easily calculate summary statistics for each channel via `image[,,1]` or `image[,,2]` or `image[,,3]`.